# Inconsistency getting data from Firebase Database with the same data class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

On my Firebase realtime database I have two main branches for debug and release builds. The debug branch works fine but when the release branch is fetched, the `price` field always has a zero as value after being converted to either map or list below, while the other three fields reflect correct values from the DB. Please note that having the field as integer or with a decimal on the DB makes no difference. This is how my data looks like:

[image: Database preview]

This is my data class with the issue

```
data class JsonProducto(var id: String,
                    var name: String,
                    var description: String,
                    var price: Double) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this(
            "id",
            "name",
            "desc",
            0.0
    )

    constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
            source.readString(),
            source.readString(),
            source.readString(),
            source.readDouble()
     )

     override fun describeContents() = 0

     override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(dest) {
        writeString(id)
        writeString(name)
        writeString(description)
        writeDouble(price)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<JsonProducto> = object : Parcelable.Creator<JsonProducto> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): JsonProducto = JsonProducto(source)
            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<JsonProducto?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried two approaches to convert the data snapshot to my class, both with same results:

**Serialization way number 1**

```
val mapper = object : GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, JsonProducto>>() {}
val list = arrayListOf<JsonProducto>()
val map = dataSnapshot.getValue(mapper)

map?.forEach {
      list.add(it.value)
}
```

**Serialization way number 2**

```
val list: MutableList<JsonProducto> = mutableListOf() 

dataSnapshot.children.mapNotNullTo(list) { 
     it.getValue<JsonProducto>(JsonProducto::class.java) 
}
```

Any ideas of why this behavior is occurring? I appreciate your time.

***EDIT:***

Still trying to figure out what is going on here, I did some experiments and the results still shock me: I changed the DB field's name to `precio` in only one of the products on the working branch, and also renamed the data class member to that and now all the fields show zero except the one I renamed. However, the non-working branch still shows zeroes, no matter what. This is very weird.

Comment: I noticed that if you accidentally (or not) name a field with a trailing space it will be recognized as a different field. I double checked that it's not happening in this case

Comment: Can you verify this use case : If the value of price is 20(Integer) instead of 25.1(Double) then is it working or not ? It shouldn't be a problem but I just want to confirm it.

Comment: @mark922 makes no difference if I store an integer or double

Comment: could you, just for the sake of having tried, use a Java class instead of Kotlin and try it with that?

Comment: also, what values do you get if you read the field manually like 'snapshot.child("price").getValue()'?

Comment: @A.Kuchinke I have not. Though it's a possible solution, I would think of it as incomplete. Either that or we may have discovered a big bug on Firebase or Kotlin. The snapshot values reflect what is on the DB, the problem arises after serialization. I will try using a Java class.

Comment: when testing with plain Java, make sure to try both double and Double (boxing), I doubt that it will make a difference, since auto boxing/unboxing is a thing, but you never know

Comment: So after creating the Java class alternative and refactoring adapters, viewholders and several references, I started getting weird exceptions and obfuscated class names. I was in a hurry trying to finish a feature so I had to stash all those changes and work with my original Kotlin class. As if it wasn't strange enough already, the Kotlin class started to work on both branches/variants once I checked-out the original commit I was working on. I also ran a diff between the "failing" changes and the current changes and there's nothing special or evidence that points to where the error was.

Comment: The Java class works as well now. @A.Kuchinke if you want to post your answer I will grant the bounty for your help.